How can I make a Helm chart (client) wait for a dependent Helm chart (server) to be fully deployed before starting its own deployment?
I'm currently working with Helm charts, where I have a "client" Helm chart that has a direct dependency on a "server" Helm chart. The server chart needs to be fully deployed and ready before the client chart can be deployed.
I want to ensure that Helm waits for the successful deployment of the server chart before starting the deployment of the client chart. Specifically, I need to know if there's a way to:
Wait for the server chart to be fully deployed, including all services and pods being in the "Running" state.
Trigger the client chart deployment only after the server chart has been successfully deployed.
I've looked into Helm hooks, but I'm not sure how to implement this dependency in a way that ensures the client doesn't start until the server is fully up and running.
What I’ve tried so far:

I’ve experimented with Helm’s dependencies section, but it doesn’t seem to provide a way to control the order of deployment.
I also tried using helm upgrade --wait, but it seems to only wait for the client chart itself and not its dependencies.


Helm doesn't have this capability, also see Helm wait till dependency deployment are ready on kubernetes.  What leads to the must be fully deployed dependency?  Can the client retry its connections on failure (which will also tolerate temporary outages in the server), or is there a problem with letting the client be in CrashLoopBackOff state for a bit until everything comes up?

It's required for an update to update server pods first and only afterwards the client, in such a case server pods (statefulset) will have rolling update, it allows client to not lost connection to servers (there at least 2) after servers are updated the client is updated as well, but if we start updating them simultaneously, it will lead to the problem with client connecting to servers and we will have downtime. The stack is Apache Ignite.

It's all but inevitable that you will have old clients talking to new servers during an upgrade, and it's all but inevitable that you will have dropped connections during an upgrade.  If your client and server are so closely coupled that they must be running exactly the same code base, you should combine them together into a single process.
